# Python3 exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to make a simple program (for learning purposes) using exception handling. 
What I'm trying to do is:

```
try:
    x = int(input())
except ValueError as var:
    # HERE I WANT TO USE THE 'x' STRING VALUE
```

I know about the the various ways to use the **exception message** (for instance by using `str(var)`).

For example, if the input is `bla` which would cause a ValueError exception, `print(var)` outputs `invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'bla'`, which is not really usable.

However, I created this program that should use `str(var)` to my advantage:

```
try:
    x = int(input())
except ValueError as var:
    s = str(var)
    print('Exception message: ' +s)
    i=0
    while (s[i] != '\''):
            i = i+1
        i = i+1
        print_str = ''
        while (s[i] != '\''):
            print_str = print_str + str(s[i])
            i++
        print('print_str = ' + print_str)
```

This program would probably work after a few changes..

So my question is: Is there a more direct way to get the 'x' string value?

Comment: Yes, `i++` is invalid syntax. It has nothing to do with exception handling.

Comment: Python is not C++ nor Java.

Comment: Fixed it, my bad(probably because I use C++ more often). That lower program was not the main purpose of this question anyway..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access `x` in the `except` because it was *never assigned* - the exception is thrown somewhere in `int(input(...))`, before `x =` happens. Instead, do:

```
x = input(...)
try:
    x = int(x)
except ValueError:
    print("Couldn't make '{0}' an integer.".format(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Furthering [jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s response, you cannot catch most `SyntaxError`s as they happen *at compile time*. Thus there's no hope whatsoever of even running the code, never mind recovering from the error.